# Why is the probability that a prime p is a factor of a number n equal to 1/p

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

I'm learning some number theory and I can't seem to understand why this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ought to specify a distribution before you ask a question like this, because there is *no* uniform distribution on all of the natural numbers, so there is no particularly natural choice.

However, what we *can* say is that if you take a large interval of natural numbers, and take a uniform distribution on them, the probability that a given number is a multiple of $m$ is roughly $1/m$. To see this, simply observe that it is equivalent to it being $0\mod m$, and there are $m$ things that you can be mod $m$, so any distribution in which they will be equally likely will give $1/m$ as the probability of any one.

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "take a uniform distribution."

Comment: @daniel: I was speaking kind of informally. I mean if you have a random variable that takes each value from the set I specified (a large interval of natural numbers) with equal probability.

Answer (score 5):

The probability that $p$ is a factor of $n$, $1\leq n \leq kp$, is
$$
P_k = \frac {\lvert \{p, 2p, \dotsc, kp \} \rvert} {\lvert \{1, 2, \dotsc, kp \} \rvert} = \frac k {kp} = \frac 1 p
$$
So the probability that $p$ is a factor of $n\in \mathbb N$ is
$$
\lim_k P_k = \frac 1 p
$$